# Deleting rest of line after X ":"

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I've got a text file that has many lines. All that I care about is grabbing the first two words separated by a ":" and delete everything else after that.

Let's imagine the text file's contents look like this. The amount of ":" is random, I only want the first two words.

Sweet:Candy:Bear:Heaven:Ball
Mac:Cheese:Sauce:Code
Kebab:Shop:Space

I want to keep the first two words seperated by a ":" and delete everything else after that.

So I want to end up with something like this:

Sweet Candy
Mac Cheese
Kebab Shop

Reply to @Zabuza

With the current code below, I get this output:
Sweet
Candy
Sweet, Mac
Candy, Cheese
Sweet, Mac, Kebab
Candy, Cheese, Shop

```
public void formatAccounts() throws InterruptedException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] parts = line.split(":");
            a.add(parts[0]);
            b.add(parts[1]);

            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println(b);

            sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem with the code? Doesn't it work? What is the current output? You should always add this too.

Comment: Split them by ':'  `String[] parts = yourString.split(":"); ` and take the first two items concatenated with ':' -> `String result = parts[0] + ":" +parts[1]`

Comment: Do you actually need to delete the following tokens from the file?

Comment: you may want to store the items in some collection ("Sweet Candy", "Mac Chesse"...). once you have read all the data from your file, overwrite it with the contents of your collection.

Comment: @Zabuza Please refer to my edit in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void formatTxtFile() throws InterruptedException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parts = line.split(":");
            System.out.println(parts[0] + " " +parts[1]);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> Create a file any where, and try to run the above code.you will get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 Streams you can simplify it to something like this:

```
Path pathToFile = Paths.get("test.txt");
Files.lines(pathToFile).map(l -> l.split(":")).forEach(a -> System.out.println(a[0] + " " + a[1]));
```

First you make a reference to the input file:

`Path pathToFile = Paths.get("nameOfFile.txt");`

With `Files.lines()` you fetch all the lines from the file and then by using `map()` you split each line into an array of strings and then finally you print out the first two elements onto the console.